# PHP:Issue with form submit

Tags: php, forms, post, submit

I have a table in my page and in each row of table I have some values for each commodity and in the last colum of the row I have 'Edit' button which sends data to some other php page.

For this using below using (PHP) FORM and trying to POST values on same page itself. My issue is I'am unable to retrieve values as given in the commented statements below.

It is working just fine if I use just HTML form, but I do not want to use as the table is very big and info can be easily seen at 'view code' on explorer page and the information is little confidential.  So was thinking of going to only PHP form.

Below is my code.

```
<FORM METHOD="post" ACTION="inventory.php">
    <?php '<input name="number" type="hidden" id="number"  value="'. $list[$i] .'">'?>
    <?php '<input name="model" type="hidden" id="model"  value="'.$model[$i].'"> '?>
    <?php '<input name="details" type="hidden" id="details"  value="'. $detail[$i].'">'?>
    <?php '<input name="type" type="hidden" id="type" value="'.$type[$i].'">'?>
    <?php echo '<button type="submit" class="button" value="'.$list[$i] .'" name="edit">Edit</button>';?> </FORM> 

if (isset ($_POST['edit']))  
{
    echo $_POST['edit'];               // Able to retrieve value of number (In chrome explorer), In (IE) it just displays as 'Edit'
    echo $_POST['number'];             // Not able to retrieve any value for this
    echo $model=$_POST['model'];       // Not able to retrieve any value for this
    echo $details=$_POST['details'];   // Not able to retrieve any value for this
    echo $type=$_POST['type'];         // Not able to retrieve any value for this
}
```

Comment: Sorry, you have to go back to start and understand how php works. What you ask does not make any sense. PHP is a language to produce html which is the only way to render a form inside a browser. So whether you create that html form by using html (an editor) or php (a script) does not make any difference. Learn about what php is and what it does!

Comment: There is no concept of a PHP Only form, Even your current form can be seen in browser if one view's source. End of the day it has to convert output to  HTML no matter which programming language you use on backend, so I would suggest don't complicate things for you following a PHP only form concept

Comment: Where is $list defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not echo ur input box, how it can be render

For e.g 
u should write

```
<?php echo '<input name="number" type="hidden" id="number"  value="'. $list[$i] .'">'; ?>
```

instead of

```
 <?php '<input name="number" type="hidden" id="number"  value="'. $list[$i] .'">'?>
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the error. Also add some code with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="inventory.php">
    <input name="number" type="hidden" id="number"  value="<?php echo $list[$i]; ?>">
   <input name="model" type="hidden" id="model"  value="<?php echo $model[$i];?>"> 
   <input name="details" type="hidden" id="details"  value="<?php echo $detail[$i]; ?>">
    <input name="type" type="hidden" id="type" value="<?php echo $type[$i]; ?>">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Edit" name="edit">
 </form> 

if (isset ($_POST['edit']))  
{
echo $_POST['number']; //Not able to retrive any value for this
echo $model=$_POST['model'];//Not able to retrive any value for this
echo $details=$_POST['details'];//Not able to retrive any value for this
echo $type=$_POST['type'];//Not able to retrive any value for this
}
```

Really man you should go and start learning php from the beginning.